# MFi Program by Apple

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, external-accessory, mfi

So, I have an Arduino Circuit which is serially connected with Classic Bluetooth Component (2.0). I had few questions regarding how to connect the circuit to an iPhone, which are as following :

1. Is it possible to make the connection without signing up for MFi? (Just for temporary prototype basis)
2. I researched but couldn't find any framework for connecting Classic Bluetooth Component to an iOS Device. Any sample code?
3. What exactly does MFi provide the developer? Do they provide any physical components necessary for connecting the device to the circuit?

Comment: I tried to do something, but to make it work on iOS device, you have to use BL 4.0

Comment: @NikitaZernov yea, with BLE we can always use CoreBluetooth framework. But I want support for Classic Bluetooth. If it isn't possible, is there any Apple Documentation to prove the point?

Comment: To use Bt2.0 you need to be an MFi licensee. This gives you access to an Apple chip that identifies your device. https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/ and specifically https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#4-5